# How to achieve base class and derived class concept in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

In angular js how to achieve base class and derived class concept?. My requirement In base controller I need to create some method and derived controller i need to override that method.. can anyone help me on this..
Thanks..

Comment: just include typescript in your project

Comment: Put your base classes in a **factory provider** with prototype methods. Include a constructor function to instantiate instances of those classes. You can then override the methods in your controllers.

Answer (score -1):

## 1 Non-inheritance way:

```
I think you can achieve this somehow like this:

function ChildController($injector, $scope) {
  $injector.invoke(ParentController, this, {
      $scope: $scope
  });
}
```

## 2 Prototypical inheritance

(ES5 browser support needed)

```
angular.inherits = function (ctor, superCtor) {
    ctor.super_ = superCtor;
    ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
        constructor: {
            value: ctor,
            enumerable: false
        }
    });
};
```

Usage:

```
function ChildController($scope) {
    // Invoke the parent constructor.
   ChildController.super_.apply(this, arguments);
}

angular.inherits(ChildController, ParentController);
```

Code samples from here: https://github.com/exratione/angularjs-controller-inheritance

## 3 Get Typescript

So right here you can change any method you want attached to $scope.
It's not a real inheritance, but better than nothing.

For have inheritance support you can use typescript and it'll do it for you.